Запуск на гитхабе кода на пайтон
Хочу запустить на гитхабе хэловолд на питоне, посмотрел документацию, делаю запрос в постмане:
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer xxx" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/lol/kek/actions/workflows/python-app.yml/dispatches \
  -d '{"ref":"main"}'

Ответ: Problems parsing JSON. Что-то не так с
-d '{"ref":"main"}'

Подскажите как правильно сделать, нужно просто вызвать запуск hello.py в гит экшн через запрос.
Дополнение к вопросу:
На питоне чуть заморочился и конечно всё работает. Нужно передавать пейлоад как джисон, это и так ясно, но вопрос открыт почему на гите в примере -d '{"name":"Hello"}' вот такая строка и она выдает Problems parsing JSON?
url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos"
payload = {
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "description": "This is your first repo!",
    "homepage": "https://github.com",
    "private": False,
    "is_template": True
}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ghp',
  'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, json=payload)


Надеюсь, вы этот curl запрос не в поле body в постмане вставляете?

@insolor Нет конечно Import > Raw Text, curl там работают нормально. Проблема должна быть или с этой строкой -d '{"ref":"main"}', или с python-app.yml. Но на гитхабе python-app.yml работает нормально.

Так а на питоне если {"ref":"main"} в payload отправить, то работает?

Я подозреваю, что вы postman как-то не так вводите, типа прямо в body так и пишите -d '{"ref":"main"}', а нужно просто {"ref":"main"}
